# What is wrong with my SSRS expression?

Tags: datetime, reporting-services

I am trying to conditionally format my cells in SSRS, so that if the date when that particular site becomes active is after a particular date in the past (in this case 31st Jan 2017), it should be black, and otherwise no colour.

I have tried this:

```
=IIf(datediff("dd", "2017-01-31", Fields!<datefield>.Value) > 0
    ,"Black"
    ,"Transparent"
    )
```

But nothing I try seems to make any difference (i.e. it is always transparent, even if I try swapping the relevant colours round).

What am I doing wrong?!

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of things wrong here. DateDiff compares two dates so you need to use a CDate function to convert the string (make sure you set your report language so that dates are converted accord to your locale), and also you need to specify a field to compare with. Try this (replacing MyDateField with the name of your own field):

```
=Iif(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, CDate("2017-01-31"), Fields!MyDateField.Value) > 0, "Black", Nothing)
```

Also, I've used the DateInterval enum. I know the in-line documentation suggests you can use a string (eg "dd") but that doesn't work!

Finally, you'll notice that I've used Nothing instead of "Transparent". That's because Visual Studio (if you use that) doesn't recognise Transparent as a valid colour (yes, really...) and generates a warning accordingly. If you have a lot of such expressions, these can become tiresome!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the expression below? I bet you are off with your date formatting.

```
=IIf(datediff(DateInterval.Day, Date(2017,1,31), Fields!.Value) > 0, "Black", "Transparent")
```